# in swift, in a UITextField, how to color a part of the text programmatically?

Tags: swift, text, uicolor

How to color a part of a text in UITextField programmatically?
The text is in a UITableView where each cell contains it text, and it's never the same text. So the color isn't in the same place each time. And the problem will be more complex when the user changes his location.

Is there any solution like \n or \r in the text, but for color?

Comment: You want to use [`NSAttributedString`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/113/nsattributedstring-by-example)

Comment: You need to use `NSAttributedString` to do that. But for the rest, it's up to you to know which part to color.

Comment: ok but the problem with NSAttributedString is that when the app change the location, the strings change too, and the colors goes somewhere else ...

Comment: @Monica why dont u share your code ?

Comment: "ok but the problem with NSAttributedString is that when the app change the location, the strings change too, and the colors goes somewhere else" Well, that's because your way to find which part to color is wrong? But then, that's not really an issue with NSAttributedString, no (or it's somewhere else); but then, showing your code might help, because we clearly can't guess what went wrong.